# Java - Summing big Integer with a traditional way

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

I have nested for loop :

```
String s1 = "4412";
String s2 = "0123";

int k = 0, l = 0, i3 = 0;

for (int i = s1.length() - 1; i < s1.length(); i--) {

    for (int j = s2.length() - 1; j <= i; j--) {

        k = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(s1.charAt(i)));
        l = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(s2.charAt(j)));

        i3 = k + l;

        System.out.println(i3);

    }
}
```

when I am executing this program I am getting 234 as output. because its taking last element value in the s1 and s2 . S2 keep on repeating loop like this:

```
1
321
2
321
.
.
```

so 2+3 ,2+2,2+1 like this its working . But what I am expecting is 
4412+123 = 4535

can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: So why tag C???

Comment: @SouravGhosh I will tag every language I have every heard of because SO asks me to add tags! *sigh*

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya _grrrrrrrrr_

Comment: @SouravGhosh C programmers also might work on these kind of logics know, may be they give some idea on resolving the issue.That is the reason tagged c .

Comment: @Chocopie Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: I don;t see where you generate your output. But in C and Java this will run forever due to `i<s1.length` followwed by `i--` so `i` will never get larger. ("forever" modulo overflow.)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but i suspect the error is in `i<s1.length` or `s1.length()-1`

Comment: @Aparna what are you even doing in the program? *I am getting 234* where is the output? What are your outputting? The local `i3` is not even being used. What is `2474`?

Comment: `(int j=s2.length()-1;j<s2.length;j--)` this really makes no sense.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I want to add two big integer values. If i have int i =56789657896789, int j = 5664354. I want to add i+j . I am trying to do that in java programatically

Comment: Maybe try `i<s1.length();` -> `i>=0;` And then you need to handle overflow when adding digits.

Answer (score 0):

You coud use split with reverse String and loop throw your arrays like this :

```
String s1 = "4421";
String s2 = "321";
//reverse and split your string
String[] spl1 = new StringBuilder(s1).reverse().toString().split("");//[1,2,4,4]
String[] spl2 = new StringBuilder(s2).reverse().toString().split("");//[1,2,4,4]
String result = "";
int max = spl1.length > spl2.length ? spl1.length : spl2.length;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    int k = spl1.length <= i ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(spl1[i]);
    int l = spl2.length <= i ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(spl2[i]);
    result += (k + l) + "";

}
System.out.println(result);//result 2474
```

**The Idea is :**

1. reverser your Strings 12345 -> 54321
2. split your Strings [5,4,3,2,1]
3. find the max between your arrays
4. loop throw your array and make the addition, if the input not exist use 0, `spl1.length <= i ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(spl1[i]);`
5. add the addition to your result.

---

**Edit**

[Lets back to school](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition) :

[image: Addition]

you can use this instead, the idea is simple :

```
String s1 = "5768956788678907689076890076544765433564376543564";
String s2 = "657687986578905438732902587349320254893";
String[] spl1 = new StringBuilder(s1).reverse().toString().split("");
String[] spl2 = new StringBuilder(s2).reverse().toString().split("");
String result = "";
int max = spl1.length > spl2.length ? spl1.length : spl2.length;
int rest = 0;
int sum;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    int k = spl1.length <= i ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(spl1[i]);
    int l = spl2.length <= i ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(spl2[i]);

    sum = k + l + rest;
    if (sum > 9) {
        rest = 1;
        sum = sum - 10;
    } else {
        rest = 0;
    }
    result = (i + 1 == max ? sum + rest * 10 : sum) + result;

}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: thanks for response. Here I want to add two integers 4421+321 = 4535 know.

Comment: are you joking me, then why you do all that and parse your Strings? then use a+b to get the result @Chocopie

Comment: sorry for irritating you . Actually my idea is to add big integer like int i = 5768956788678907689076890076544765433564376543564, int j=657687986578905438732902587349320254893. So obviously it will not fit in integer , So I took string . So 1st I am trying with small example to make you understand.

Comment: check my answer @Chocopie hope this what you want to do :)

Answer (score 0):

try these code

```
    String s1 = "4412";
    String s2 = "0123";
    int k = 0, l = 0;

    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, length = 0;
    length = s1.length() > s2.length() ? s1.length() : s2.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i < s1.length()) {
            k = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(s1.charAt(i)));
            num1 = num1 * 10 + k;
        }
        if (i < s2.length()) {
            l = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(s2.charAt(i)));
            num2 = num2 * 10 + l;
        }
    }
    int result = num1 + num2;
    System.out.println(num1 + "+" + num2 + "=" + result);
```

Comment: did you tried with `String s1 = "5768956788678907689076890076544765433564376543564";
String s2 = "657687986578905438732902587349320254893";` ?

Comment: for this you can use BigInteger, no need to parse string char by char.

Comment: no biginteger is not enough to solve this problem did you try it?